Dynamically Handle Android Child Recycler View Data
Is it possible to handle the child recycler view data dynamically without refreshing parent item list?
I want to update my child view data after selecting a parent item. I don't want that same child list to be applied to all the parent items. I have tried many solutions. I would really appreciate someone if you can help me get out of this recycler view linking problem.
Here's the link to my github code for the files I am using to achieve this goal.
Note: It does not contain entire code as I am working on my work project.
Github:

Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you read How to ask a question and make this better?
